# Is it possible to make glares brighter

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have planned to use the glare as a simple light flash, kind of camera flare.

I noticed the glares are quite dark:

[image]

It looks nice with dark background, but on the main animation, it pretty much vanishes.

Question: Is there a possibility to made these brighter? I tried to use "Bright/Contrast", but that impact to the full area. I did not manage to impact only to the glares.

Comment: Perhaps use the color correction node to raise the highlights without affecting the lows.

Comment: @AllenSimpson perfect ! I'll try that ! Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you’ve got the glare affect set to low. Turn it up. If that doesn’t work, separate the glare effect from the main image, brighten the glare, and then mix them back together, instead of using the glare effect’s automatic mixing.

Comment: The "low" option on the glare node does not adjust it's intensity. It is meant to choose a resolution for the glare node to compute on. It is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @EricXue I disagree. While it does only make the glare larger not brighter, that means that the area that still has most of the original light intensity is larger. You can’t really make it much brighter without just making flat white because of the monitor’s max output range.

Comment: I did a few test renders, and the outcome was the complete opposite of what you describe. The "High" setting on the glare node actually produced the glare with the smallest area, and the "Low" setting produced the largest glare. It seems that higher resolutions define the area of brightness much better.

Comment: @EricXue 8-/ your blender is from the twilight zone.

Answer (score 0):

using the multiplier is good, cause multiplying a smaller number has less effect than multiplying a big number, you can do a bit of subtraction if you want.
I am mainly a modeler, I am not that good at shaders and compositing. Hopefully, this helps.

[image: screenshot1]